# Generate .build file from Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

Can I make a myproject.build file matching my solution in Visual studio 2012 (csharp aspnetmvc project)?

I'd like to answer myself that VS does this already but when I look at my solution files there is no .build file. On the other hand... I have 2 other solutions that has .build files. (I believe they both started as VS2010 solutions, contrary to my latest) So why do I have a .build file in one project and not in the other?

Answer (score 1):

Close Visual Studio, Add a global environment variable "MsBuildEmitSolution" with a value of "1", restart Visual Studio then compile.  MSBuild will save in the same folder as the .SLN the autogenerated project file (SolutionFileName.SLN.MetaProj) in MSBUILD format.

Comment: This does not appear to work in VS 2013 at least. Only works if you invoke msbuild directly, not via devenv